# Individual video views facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Anyone know if there is a way to get the number of views per each video on a fan page?

Through the graph API I am able to get the number of like son a video I was just wondering if it was possible to get the number of views, I know I can get the whole video views from the Insights but that is from the whole page and I am looking to see which is the most popular video

Per this link I am guessing it is not possible, just wondering if anyone has any other ideas.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server hosts the videos, then you can use your server logs to run reports.
If a third party hosts the videos, then you can contact them to see if they offer any view counts.
If facebook hosts the videos, then you will need to use Insights.

You'd be best off by having your own server host each of the videos so you can easily keep track of views, etc.

Comment: this case Videos are uploaded to facebook so Facebook is the one hosting the videos, insights gives me video views as a whole so if I have 3 videos I just know how many times the 3 videos have been watched on a particular day but I want to know how many times each video was watched, do you know the way to get it Through Insights?

Comment: As you can see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_content the video view counts are now deprecated.  Hence why my last paragraph urged you to host the videos on your own site, so you can collect any stat you want from your own servers's logs.